# javascript function event... send from one function to another - maybe simple

Tags: javascript

Here is a little story... I want to make a for loop that makes make 's to addenventlisteners so when I move over :hover/onmouseover it should shift bewteen 2 colors. But I can not figure out how I get the keyword down to the function redB ...

But I dont know if I am on the rigth way...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    document.getElementById("sek2" + i + ).addEventListener("mouseover", Over(this));
    document.getElementById("sek2" + i + ).addEventListener("mouseout", Out(this));
  }
});

function greyB(x) {
  x.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
}

function redB(x) {
  x.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: `.addEventListener("mouseover", greyB)` and `.addEventListener("mouseout", redB)`

Comment: Some advice, use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with ".sek2" as the selector, then assign class sek2 to all 10 elements on the page.  No need to use ids for elements that you treat very similarly.

Comment: Yeah but he has to change also the functions themselves. `x` will be the event, they should be `x.target.style.backgroundColor`

Answer (score 0):

you are calling the wrong `function` name and if you use `$(document).ready()` you need ah jquery  library

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Js code**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        document.getElementById("sek2" + i + ).addEventListener("mouseover", greyB);
        document.getElementById("sek2" + i + ).addEventListener("mouseout", redB);
      }

    });

    function greyB() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    }

    function redB() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla javascript, close to your current code, this is as easy as:

```js
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    document.getElementById("sek2" + i).addEventListener("mouseover", function(){ greyB(this); });
    document.getElementById("sek2" + i).addEventListener("mouseout", function(){ redB(this); });
}

function greyB(x) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
}
function redB(x) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "red";

}
```

```html
<div id="sek20">Mouse over me</div>
```

If using jQuery this is even easier:

```js
$("[id^='sek2']").on('mouseover', function(){
   $(this).css('background-color','grey');
}).on('mouseout',function(){
   $(this).css('background-color','red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sek20">Mouse over me</div>
```

Comment: Hi can you please give an explanation on this: [id^='sek2_'] [attribute^=value] $("[title^='Tom']") All elements with a title attribute value starting with "Tom"   ----SORRY

Comment: @jokerper you were looking for items where the `id` starts with `sek2` - `[id^='sek2']` as a selector does just that! But you shouldnt be using id's you should be using a class - then the selector is just `.myclass`.

Comment: Can you terll me about the language where can I look further because it look's like a very nice language. Maybe a link or so.

Comment: @jokerper jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you looking for?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.classList.add('square');
    newDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", greyB);
    newDiv.addEventListener("mouseout", redB);
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(newDiv);
  }
});

function greyB() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
}

function redB() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
.square {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended with this solution, but can anyone tell there to go getting more information about this code. What kind of language maybe a link to some place. So I not getting different code to play with futher.

Thanks...

```js
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    document.getElementById("sek2" + i).addEventListener("mouseover", function(){ greyB(this); });
    document.getElementById("sek2" + i).addEventListener("mouseout", function(){ redB(this); });
}

function greyB(x) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
}
function redB(x) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "red";

}
```

```html
<div id="sek20">Mouse over me</div>
```